# Why is my data reset when I navigate back to my previous screen?

Tags: flutter, dart

I added data in a page and moved to a different page.

When I navigated back to my previous page, I don't see my data. Can you explain why?

Here's my code:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
    _keyController?.text =
        _AddProductSpecificationState.productFeatureKey[widget.index] ?? '';
    _valueController?.text =
        _AddProductSpecificationState.productFeatureValue[widget.index] ?? '';
  });
  return Row(children: [
    Expanded(
      flex: 1,
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8),
        child: TextFormField(
          maxLength: 500,
          controller: _keyController,
          maxLines: 1,
          onChanged: (values){
            if(values.isNotEmpty){
              _AddProductSpecificationState.productFeatureKey[widget.index]=values;
            }
          },
          validator: (v) {
            if (v?.trim().isEmpty == true)
              return context
                  .getStrings()
                  .pleaseEnterProductSpecificationFeature;
            return null;
          },
          onSaved: (key) {
            _AddProductSpecificationState.productFeatureKey[widget.index] =
                key;
          },
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
            hintText: context.getStrings().feature,
            border: UnderlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: AppColors.LIGHT_GRAY_COLOR)),
            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: AppColors.LIGHT_GRAY_COLOR)),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      flex: 1,
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8),
        child: TextFormField(
          maxLength: 500,
          controller: _valueController,
          maxLines: 1,
          onChanged: (values){
            if(values.isNotEmpty){
              _AddProductSpecificationState.productFeatureValue[widget.index]=values;
            }
          },
          validator: (v) {
            if (v?.trim().isEmpty == true)
              return context
                  .getStrings()
                  .pleaseEnterProductSpecificationValue;
            return null;
          },
          onSaved: (key) {
            _AddProductSpecificationState.productFeatureValue[widget.index] =
                key;
          },
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
            hintText: context.getStrings().value,
            border: UnderlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: AppColors.LIGHT_GRAY_COLOR)),
            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: AppColors.LIGHT_GRAY_COLOR)),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ]);
}
```

Comment: what is in your screen 1 and screen 2? problem seems less descriptive

Comment: Hi @Sunil gohil, It seems you're new to StackOverflow. I've edited your question. Still it is unclear what data you have added and what you're expecting when navigating back without reading the code completely. You need to explain more to attract responders.

Comment: You might need to read this for persisting data between pages: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/intro